# What are the resource savings of springboot webflux/reactive/coroutines vs traditional/MVC - is it worth it?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

Springboot has a few of methods to serve web requests:

- MVC, and
- webflux using Project Reactor, which makes use of nonblocking IO to offer a reduced memory usage thread overhead, and
- webflux using kotlin coroutines

What resource usage savings can I expect from switching from MVC to webflux?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/barrett-rob/kotlin-springboot-reactive-resource-usage for a quick comparison of spring boot per-request resource usage with reactive vs traditional MVC methods.

This experiment is contrived - the difference between the three examples is just the threading behaviour at the web request handling layer. Your results will differ if you introduce more variation in underlying IO operations, but in general the following results are shown:

Traditional MVC used the most threads, Coroutines about half as much, and Reactor even less.
Traditional MVC used the most heap/memory, Coroutines less, and Reactor even less.
Some thoughts following from this:

If minimising cost of computing per request is your only goal then choose Reactor, at the expense of imperative coding styles.
Coroutines give definite memory & threading advantages over MVC without changing coding styles.